# Insert checkbox button into database and display in laravel with ajax

Tags: laravel

I am using Laravel framework in my project ,I have checkbox button ,and I want to store the value of this checkbox (when the user check it) into database and display them in ajax , can you help me ,please ?

Comment: Your comment is vague. we would like to see an attempt at solving the problem

Comment: ok,I have a classes.blade.php ,and in this page the user must insert the name of the class as a normal input field ,and this page contain a group of checkbox button ,so the user must check collection or one from these checkbox ,and after the user click on add button ,these data must be inserted into database and display them in ajax ,, so I did not know how to insert these checkbox value  into database and display them in ajax  with laravel ,so that is my problem